# Get data from TextField and insert into database with a click of a button

Tags: java, database, user-interface

I recently started coding and I am trying to create a Registration Form on Java but I can't get my "Register" button to get data from TextField and save it on my database.
Here is what I have I am completely lost .

```
     Register.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {  
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
{  if(fn.getText().equals("")||fn.getText()==null||ln.getText().equals("")||
   ln.getText()==null ||id.getText().equals("")||id.getText()==null ||gpa.getText().equals("")||gpa.getText()==null)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter all Fields","Error",0);
     else{
        String First_Name=fn.getText();
        String Last_Name=ln.getText();
        String ID=id.getText();
        String GPA =gpa.getText();
       try{
           Connection connection=null;
           Connection conn=null;
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB","root","");         
     PreparedStatement pstmt = null;         
     String query = "INSERT INTO CourseDemo(First_Name, Last_Name, ID, GPA)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
     
     pstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
      int status = pstmt.executeUpdate();
           if(status > 0) {
            System.out.println("Record is inserted successfully !!!");
         }
       }
       catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
           
       }            
       catch(Exception f){
         f.printStackTrace();
      }          
         
     }         
}
      });
```

Comment: following naming conventions, indent your code properly, don't hide exceptions. Also, write code that makes sense. Can you spot the problem with this? fn.getText().equals("")||fn.getText()==null

Comment: Also, it would help us being able to spot any issues, if you mentioned what the error you have is

Comment: Between the statement `conn.prepareCall(query);` and `int status = pstmt.executeUpdate();` you do not fill any values into your prepared statement ... that is one issue.
You need to call something like: `pstmt.setString(1, First_Name);` etc, before calling the execute method.

Comment: @Stultuske I was trying to make it so when the button is clicked and if there was no data filled in the Text Field  it would show an error message.

Comment: @Stultuske there is no error message when i fill the form and click the button it doesn't do any thing.

Comment: @Robel have you debugged your code, or added some basic print statements (at least) to check why not?

Comment: And please declare and initialize in-line. Having multiple lines where one can do, without regards to any other functionality, is pure useless.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);

pstmt.setString(1, First_Name);
pstmt.setString(2, Last_Name);
pstmt.setString(3, ID); // consider setInt() might be more appropriate
pstmt.setString(4, GPA);

int status = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

> **Supplying Values for PreparedStatement Parameters**
>
> You must supply values in place of the question mark placeholders (if there are any)
> before you can execute a PreparedStatement object. Do this by calling
> one of the setter methods defined in the PreparedStatement class.

Comment: he is trying to get an error message if nothing is filled in (according to his comments), so I doubt this is relevant

Answer (score 0):

A few things going on here that need to be addressed:

1. a) The  query parameters weren't added to the statement

   b) Either handle the exceptions or throw them

Refactoring the code a bit:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        {
            if (invalidInput()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter all Fields", "Error", 0);
            } else {
                String First_Name = fn.getText();
                String Last_Name = ln.getText();
                String ID = id.getText();
                String GPA = gpa.getText();
                
                Connection conn = null;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB", "root", "");
                    String query = "INSERT INTO CourseDemo(First_Name, Last_Name, ID, GPA)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    pstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
                    pstmt.setString(1, First_Name);
                    pstmt.setString(2, Last_Name);
                    pstmt.setString(3, ID);
                    pstmt.setString(4, GPA);
                    int status = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                    if (status > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Record is inserted successfully !!!");
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    // todo show error message or throw
                } catch (Exception f) {
                    // todo show error message or throw
                } finally {
                    if (pstmt != null) {
                        try {
                            pstmt.close();
                        } catch (SQLException s) {
                            // todo show error message
                        }
                    }
                    if (conn != null) {
                        try {
                            conn.close();
                        } catch (SQLException s2) {
                            // todo show error message
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Where you also have a helper method for the validation

```
boolean invalidInput() {
    return fn.getText() == null || fn.getText().equals("") || ln.getText() == null || ln.getText().equals("") || id.getText() == null || id.getText().equals("") || gpa.getText() == null || gpa.getText().equals("");
}
```

2. The validation (checks on your inputs) had to be refactored because there were null checks after other checks that required a non-null value (which would have thrown a null pointer). Note that here it's not straightforward to test a method with all this stuff in OR (`||`) and it would be better and more maintainable to split the checks up into different statements.

Another comment: which jdk are you using? If you're using java 7 or later, look into using [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

In the `todo` comments you have to either handle the exceptions that can be raised or throw them.

Comment: it might be good to suggest field.getText().trim().isEmpty() over field.getText().equals("")

Comment: If the answers provided are helpful consider upvoting or marking as accepted